# Functional domain driven design using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, domain-driven-design

I recently came across an article that seems to provide a really good approach to functional domain driven design using TypeScript.  However, there is one part of the article in particular that I need more clarity on, coding-wise.  In the article they create a type Query that uses a mapped type but it is not clear what they are trying to achieve in that part of the code.  I read up on type mapping but am missing the goal of this example.

The article containing the example:

https://antman-does-software.com/functional-domain-driven-design-simplified

The code I need clarity on:

```
type Repository<T> = {
   getMatching: (query: Query<T>) => Promise<T[]>;
   getById: (id: string) => Promise<T | undefined>;
   create: (item: Omit<T, 'id'>) => Promise<T>;
   update: (item: T) => Promise<T | undefined>;
   upsert: (item: T) => Promise<T>;
   delete: (id: string) => Promise<undefined | MissingEntityError>;
 };

type Query<T> = {
  [k: keyof T]: { operator: Operator, value: unknown },
}
```

I am trying to understand the inner workings for the type Query and how it would be beneficial in this case.  I am relatively new to TypeScript.

Comment: Are you asking what `Query<T> = { ... ]` *means* or are you asking why it's useful?

Comment: That's invalid syntax, so I'd say it's not beneficial at all .  Could you make sure you're posting a [mre]?

Comment: I am asking what it means in this example.  I was not sure how to translate it's meaning.  Plus, it seemed like it should by "k in keyof T" from the example I looked up online.

Comment: Since you got that invalid syntax directly from the tutorial then I'd say it doesn't mean anything and is not beneficial.  If it were a mapped type it would indeed be `k in keyof T`... except that `k` is a *type* parameter (and not a dummy key expression) as such would conventionally be written `K in keyof T`.  What should we do for this question? It seems like it could be closed as "caused by a typo", unless you're looking for something else (and in which case, what?)

Comment: Overall, I was trying to understand that whole line, minus the typo.  Trying to understand what the purpose of this line served.  Granted, as a newbie to typescript it looked like it was a one-liner that could be add up to something big. Either way, I wanted to understand what was happening there.

Comment: Hmm, if you're not asking about the typo then you should probably remove it.  And if you're asking about code then it should be a [mre] and include all the relevant definitions as plaintext in your post (external links are good supplements but are not sufficient); right now I don't know what `Operator` or `MissingEntityError` are.  And ultimately it seems you're asking for an opinion, since I'm not sure how we could answer authoritatively about the purpose or utility of third party code. So that's typo + needs details + opinion, all of which are closeworthy. Could you [edit] to clear it up?

Comment: I just glanced at that article and gist of it is sensible enough but I have no idea what that Query type is supposed to represent (beyond a query, obvs). There's no definition for anything else in that little block. I don't think we can answer this.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be:

```
type Query<T> = {
  [k in keyof T]: { operator: Operator, value: unknown },
}
```

It means that a `Query` should be an object where each property should have an `operator` and a `value`. `Query` is beneficial because it ensures that objects have the structure that `Repository` expects.

To break it down into smaller more understandable pieces, let's start with:

```
type Query = {}
```

The above means a `Query` should be an object.

```
type Query<T> = {}
```

The `<T>` above makes Query a generic type that uses the `T` object as a parameter. Basically, it'll use information from the `T` object to define the `Query` object.

It doesn't need to be called `T`. I'll rename it to `MyObject` for better understanding:

```
type Query<MyObject> = {
  [k in keyof MyObject]: {},
}
```

The `[k in keyof MyObject]` is an index signature which means the properties of a Query will vary. The `{}` means each property should be an object. The `k` stands for key, and `k in keyof MyObject` means that `Query` will have the same keys or properties of MyObject.

It doesn't need to be called `k`. I'll rename it to `property` for better understanding. So putting it all together:

```
type Query<MyObject> = {
  [property in keyof MyObject]: { operator: Operator, value: unknown },
}
```

The `{ operator: Operator, value: unknown }` above means each property should be an object with an `operator` and a `value`.

Here's how `Query` might be used:

```
const myQuery : Query = {
  select: { operator: equalTo, value: "*"},
  from: { operator: equalTo, value: "my_table"},
}
```

There we see that `myQuery` is an object where each property has an `operator` and a `value`.